# Internet connection in Germany for iPad 2nd gen

Tags: ipad, wifi, cellular-data

I have to say first, I am clueless about it all, including the jargon. I have just spent phone time with ATT, and I have learned I will not be able to tether (that means create a hot spot from my iPhone 3GS, right?). I have the lowest data plan now, but am willing to change to the highest limit for the trip. but, apparently that won't make a difference in the ability to tether.

I have to be able to tether with my iPad. I can't even understand if I will be able to use my cell at all, muchless live stream or upload. I just don't know enough about any of this stuff. A numbered list of exactly what to do as well as some definitions would be so helpful. Tech jargon related to this subject will not make sense to me, keep in mind. I'm not stupid, I just haven't been exposed to it all.

Comment: This may not be a question appropriate for this forum but without understanding technical aspects you won't be able to understand the answer.  The question that you should be asking from AT&T is: Does your AT&T iPad support European 3G frequencies?  The answer you're more then likely to receive is no.

Comment: FWIW, I tried unsuccessfully to set up AT&T international data roaming that supported tethering.  According to AT&T it wasn't possible, although I suspect there might be an unofficial way of getting it to work.  In any case, you'll want to review the [AT&T international options page](http://www.wireless.att.com/learn/international/roaming/affordable-world-packages.jsp#data)

Answer (score 1):

Forget AT&T in Germany! 
Go to any local store (in Germany) and buy Prepaid Internet service SIM card. For that your device has to be UNLOCKED. That means the AT&T is not longer the sole provider (ask them). If you do not understand the Unlocking stuf, just ask.